# identify the selected td using javascript in html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a table which contain 100 rows and td.  like see below

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="artcle-title" >
  <tr>
   <td>Artcle details 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Artcle details 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Artcle details 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Artcle details 4</td>
  </tr>
....
 </table>
```

When a user click on a td content, i want to display a separate content table with respect to the selected table.i want to display the content in a separate table. I meant out side the selected table.
 My question is that

How i identify which table is selected ( with out passing any argument eg: funshow(td_id1) etc)

Does any one know this?

Comment: which javascript framework are you using? e.g: jQuery, prototype, dojo etc

Comment: I know simple java script and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach a `click` handler to each `tr` element in the `table`. Once clicked this handler will be invoked and you will be able to get the underlying DOM element. Once you have the element you can modify its contents. Depending on whether you are using a javascript framework or not the way to achieve this will vary. For example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(function() {
    $('table tr').click(function() {
        $(this).html('<td>some new contents</td>');
    });
});
```

Comment: actually  i want to display the content in a separate table. I meant out side the selected table

Comment: Where on the other table? A new row? An existing one (if yes how is this row identified)?

Comment: Thanks 
 The first table have an Id id="artcle-title". Out side this table i have a new table which have an Id id="artcle-details". In article details table , I want to display only one  row content. And all other should be not display .

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework? In jQuery you could try `$('#artcle-details tr:first td').html('New content');`

Comment: Very Great..Thanks,

 hope that reaching to success..
html('New content'): the new content is dynamic. SO I have  to use the display and block property , 
Please advise me in How to display a particular row and other must be hide...

Answer (score 1):

On the table, place an onclick event:

The HTML:

```
<table onclick="lineSelected(event||window.event)">...</table>
```

The javascript:

```
function lineSelected(ev){
  var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
  // target is the clicked element (TD, TR,...)
  // Place here the code to detect which line is selected, ie:
  // content of a cell in that row, counting the lines, an id on the tr,...
}
```

This is the old way to attach events to a DOM element, but it's cross browser and easy to start. You can then start to use `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table#articles td").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(".tdcontent").html($(this).html());
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Will attach to every td in the table with the id `articles` a `click` handler. The content of the clicked td will be written into an element with the class `tdcontent`.
It shouldn't be to hard to customize this example to your own needs.

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)